# Polymer: accessibility when JS is disabled with "dom-bind"

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

When using `dom-bind` on your `index.html`: How can you ensure that some content is still visible when users browse with disabled javascript or a slow connection, resulting in slow script loading.

Of course, it is possible to put content before the `<template>` begins.
Like here, inside the `<noscript>`:

```
<body>
    <noscript>This is visible with JS disabled or slow internet connection.</noscript>
    <template is="dom-bind">
        This is not
        <iron-pages selected="0">

            <div>test1</div>
            <div>test2></div>
            <div>test3</div>

        </iron-pages>
    </template>
</body>
```

This is not desirable to me. Optimally Standard `div` or text should still be show, as they shouldn't depend on scripts at all to be rendered.

I would like to retain data-binding, that's why the `dom-bind` approach (*Polymer Start Kit* does it) is good. But I find it very irritating not seeing any content at all until all the elements are loaded (be it because JS is disabled or the internet connection is sluggish).

Comment: Use a noscript tag when JavaScirpt is disabled.

Comment: @epascarello Maybe I need to clarify, updated my post. I prefer not to explicitly set content to be seen when JS is disabled, but like standard stuff like `div` to be visible.

Comment: I have no idea what you are expecting to happen. If you want something there by default, than add something and hide it when the polymer code has rendered.

Comment: I'm with @epascarello

Comment: @epascarello It might be wishful thinking. I hoped there would be a less redundant way :/

Comment: this issue seems to be related: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/3253

Answer (score 0):

Add/remove a class to the element and toggle it from JS. Use CSS to hide the content after the class is toggled. 
Like it's don't with `unresolved` or use `unresolved` directly https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/articles/styling-elements.html#preventing-fouc

Comment: Thanks, it's useful info. However it's not quite what I was concerned about: 
That is not being able to see  the elements inside `template` tags when JS is disabled. I don't care about styling *when* scripts are succesfully loading, but about not seeing generic html elements when scripts are not loading.

Comment: With CSS I mean styles like `display: none` which allows you to control what is displayed before/after your JS runs.

Comment: sure, I got that. But have you tried putting elements into a `template` on your first page? The elements won't be shown at all, which makes any CSS useless to begin with. I guess "wir haben aneinander vorbeigeredet" ;)

The github issue I just found yesterday which I linked above, targets this very problem, and should fix the problem in the near future: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/3253

Comment: I see. I guess this needs the linked issue to be fixed then.